# User input in subprocess call?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working to automate the Wig tool in python, which will involve including a URL.

Currently I take in user input (a URL) but am having difficulty adding it to the end of the subprocess call.

```
import subprocess

var = raw_input("Enter a URL: ")

subprocess.call('python3 wig.py ', var)
```

I know this is probably a simple question, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use a list of args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the arguments as a list as @PadraicCunningham suggests:

```
args = ['python3','wig.py']
args.append(var)
subprocess.call(args)
```

If your argument list becomes long and complicated you can bring in `shlex`:

```
import shlex
args = shlex.split('python3 wig.py {}'.format(var))
subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automate_wig.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call('python3 wig.py {}'.format(var))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory...Any ideas what could be causing it?

Comment: I believe so, it works if I just run python3 wig.py google.com

Comment: yup! The directory I run this script in has wig.py in the same folder

Comment: I believe it works if I do this: process = subprocess.call('python3 wig.py {}'.format(var), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.returncode